# How to remove escaped forward slash using php?

Tags: php, regex

I am using the Google Drive API and the `refresh_token` I obtain has an escaped forward slash. While this should be valid JSON, the API won't accept it when calling `refreshToken()`. I am trying to remove the backslash using `preg_replace`:

```
$access_token = "1\/MgotwOvbwZN9MVxH5PrLR2cpvX1EJl8omgYdA9rrjx8";
$access_token = preg_replace('/\\\//', '/', $access_token);
```

I would like the returned string to be:

```
"1/MgotwOvbwZN9MVxH5PrLR2cpvX1EJl8omgYdA9rrjx8";
```

I've tried various expressions, but it either doesn't remove the backslash or it returns an empty string. Note that I don't want to remove all backslashes, only the ones escaping a forward slash.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Avoid regex and just use `str_replace`:

```php
$access_token = "1\/MgotwOvbwZN9MVxH5PrLR2cpvX1EJl8omgYdA9rrjx8";
$access_token = str_replace( '\/', '/', $access_token );
//=> 1/MgotwOvbwZN9MVxH5PrLR2cpvX1EJl8omgYdA9rrjx8
```

Comment: Thanks! Very close - I wanted to retain the /, so str_replace( '\/', '/', $s );

Comment: @svenyonson: Yes I had updated code later, use latest code from above.

Answer (score 13):

Well, there's a standard function that does just that: [`stripslashes`](http://php.net/stripslashes)

So please avoid regex, str_replace et al.

It's as simple as it takes:

```php
$access_token = stripslashes($access_token);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a different delimiter.  Here I chose to use the `~` as a delimiter instead of the `/`.

```
$access_token = "1\/MgotwOvbwZN9MVxH5PrLR2cpvX1EJl8omgYdA9rrjx8";
$access_token = preg_replace('~\\\/~', '/', $access_token);

print $access_token;
```

This returns:

```
1/MgotwOvbwZN9MVxH5PrLR2cpvX1EJl8omgYdA9rrjx8
```

Comment: This answer is technically *correct*, but I personally think `preg_replace()` is overkill for such a simple-task.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$access_token = "1\/MgotwOvbwZN9MVxH5PrLR2cpvX1EJl8omgYdA9rrjx8";
echo str_replace("\\","",$access_token);
?>
```

**Output:**

> 1/MgotwOvbwZN9MVxH5PrLR2cpvX1EJl8omgYdA9rrjx8

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you:

```
$access_token = preg_replace('|\\\\|', '', $access_token);
```

Answer (score 0):

What should happen to a string like this `1\\/Mg\otw\\\/Btow` ?

If your string uses double quote interpolated escapes, then a simple find `\/` replace `/` won't work.

You have to use this for a specific `non-\` escaped char:  `'~(?<!\\\)((?:\\\\\\\)*)\\\(/)~'`

Find - `(?<!\\)((?:\\\\)*)\\(/)`
Replace - `$1$2`

Answer (score 0):

This works for me (uses negative forward lookahead):

```
$pattern = "/(?!\/)[\w\s]+/"
preg_match($pattern, $this->name,$matches)
$this->name = $matches[0]
```

name before:
WOLVERINE WORLD WIDE INC /DE/

name after:
WOLVERINE WORLD WIDE INC DE